# Error installing pymvpa2 with pip

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, pip, deep-learning

I'm trying to install pymvpa2 in Python 2.7. using pip. I successfully installed other required modules, but I can't install pymvpa2 (I use Python 2.7 and Windows 10).
Also, I downloaded swig, but I keep getting the same error message:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd "C:\Python27\Scripts"
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pymvpa2
Collecting pymvpa2
Using cached pymvpa2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
running build_src
build_src
building extension "mvpa2.clfs.libsmlrc.smlrc" sources
building extension "mvpa2.clfs.libsvmc._svmc" sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-2.7
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs
creating build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc
swig.exe++: mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc.i
swig.exe -python -I3rd\libsvm -c++ -I3rd\libsvm -o build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc_wrap.cpp -outdir build\src.win32-2.7\mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc mvpa2\clfs\libsvmc\svmc.i
error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\MYCOM\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-uiyfnt\pymvpa2\
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out!!

Comment: pip complains about not finding "swig.exe". Have you checked that you can execute "swig.exe" from the terminal? Simply typing swig or swig.exe should help you find this out.

Comment: @Pierre de Buyl Thanks for your suggestion Pierre! Could you please explain me how to execute "swig.exe" from the terminal? Typing swig or swig.exe either from the file directory where the swig or pip is stored doesn't work...

Comment: The point is that it should work. When a command-line program is installed successfully, you can simply type its name in a terminal and it should start. swig has a page to get you started on windows: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Windows.html

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thank for so much your comments and the link!!! Now it works, thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: Cool :-) I allowed myself to transfer this to a answer

Answer (score 1):

pip complains about not finding "swig.exe". Have you checked that you can execute "swig.exe" from the terminal? Simply typing swig or swig.exe should help you find this out. When a command-line program is installed successfully, you can simply type its name in a terminal and it should start.

If swig is not available by this methods, check their special page to get you started on windows: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Windows.html